# facebook graph api get /me/scores does not work for all users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbconnect

I have the following permissions. 'user_games_activity, user_likes, friends_games_activity, read_friendlists'

I want to access the score of castleville game for all of my friend's who plays it. This is what I am doing right now.

1. getting the friends list. '/user/friends'.
2. getting user scores of all games for a friend '/friend_id/scores'
3. checking if castleville game id exists in scores array and extracting the score.

Here's the problem in step 2. The '/friend_id/score's does not return data for all users. For some it shows but for most friends the array is blank. It should show all the games or atleast some game the user plays. I tested with one of my friends id who plays dozens of games, on his timeline the scores are shown but no data with '/scores' api query. Its working with another friends id. Checked the privacy settings & app permissions for both users and all was same.

I think I am missing something. Any ideas!

Edit: The problem may be Solved. Changed the category of my app to games and now I can access the scores of all my friends (tested with few and it showed). Although now people would be clicking on Play Game in auth dialog box whereas my app is not a game.

Answer (score 3):

[According to the specification](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/scores/) the scoring system is only available if you have the category of your application set to "game".